# How do I find all the methods of a Superclass that I can Override in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I'm sorry to ask such a ridiculous question, but what window can I open in Eclipse that will expose all the methods that I can Override when I extend a class, or all the methods that are part of an Implementation.

I feel liked I've poked and prodded every obvious place and I'm just not seeing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Source -> Override/Implement methods

http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-dialog-override-method.htm

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the way mentioned by @Ajay if you want a window that displays methods you can open the "Type Hierarchy" view by by right clicking class name and "Open Type Hierarchy"